# Expected segmentation fault, as soon as assigning a value to index 1?

Tags: c, arrays, memory, memory-management, segmentation-fault

In the code snippet, I expected a segmentation fault as soon as trying to assign a value to `count[1]`. However the code continues and executes the second for-loop, only indicating a segmentation fault when the program terminates.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
        int count[1];
        int i;

        for(i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
                count[i] = i;
        }
        for(i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
                printf("%d\n", count[i]);
        }
        return 0;
}
```

Could someone explain what is happening?

**Reasons for edit:**
Improved the example code as per comments of users,
`int count[0] -> int count[1]`, 
too avoid flame wars.

Comment: Your array declaration is not valid either, the compiler should have diagnosed that according the the C Standard (it's the size you need to specify, not the highest index). Maybe put up the warning level and standard conformance testing of your code.

Comment: My array declaration was just to illustrate my point. The gcc compiler  will compile this code example and only gives a warning when specifying the `-pedantic` flag.

Comment: Your question still is suggesting a basic misunderstanding because with specifying `0` at the declaration, the index `0` is already out of bounds, not just index `1`. Thus my comment. Usually you illustrate your point with correct code, and not (as you seem to act like) with *deliberately* written wrong code. That's weird.

Comment: However, by reading the question you should have noticed that the whole point of this exercise was to illustrate incorrect code and the expected behavior. I did not ask what is wrong with the code. I asked why I am not getting a segmentation fault as soon as i'm overwriting memory. Which jalf and Nikolai N Fetissov explained.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You're writing beyond the bounds of the array. That doesn't mean you're going to get a segmentation fault. It just means that you have *undefined behavior*. Your program's behavior is no longer constrained by the C standard. Anything could happen (including the program seeming to work) -- a segfault is just one possible outcome.

In practice, a segmentation fault occurs when you try to access a memory page that is not mapped to your process by the OS. Each page is 4KB on a typical x86 PC, so basically, your process is given access to memory in 4KB chunks, and you only get a segfault if you write outside the current chunk.

With the small indices you're using, you're still staying within the current memory page, which is allocated to your process, and so the CPU doesn't detect that you're accessing memory out of bounds.

Answer (score 3):

When you write beyond the array bounds, you are probably still writing data into the area of memory under the control of your process; you are also almost certainly overwriting memory used by other software, such as heap or stack frame management code. It is only when that code executes, such as when the current function attempts to return, that your code might go awry. Actually, you really hope for a seg fault.

Answer (score 2):

Your code is broken:

```
seg.c:5: warning: ISO C forbids zero-size array ‘count’
```

Always compile with high warning levels, for example `-Wall -pedantic` for GCC.

#### Edit:

What you are effectively doing is **corrupting `main`s function [stack frame](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_frame#Structure)**. Since stack nowadays pretty much always grows down, this is what's happening:

- First loop overrides stack memory holding `main` parameters and return address to [`crt0`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crt0) routines.
- Second loop happily reads that memory.
- When `main` returns the segmentation fault is triggered since return address is fubar-ed.

This is a classic case of [buffer overrun](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffer_overrun) and is the basis of many network worms.

Run the program under the debugger and check the addresses of local variables. In GDB you can say `set backtrace past-main` so backtrace would show you all the routines leading to `main`.

By the way, the same effect could be achieved without zero-length array - just make its size smaller then number of loop iterations.

Comment: I know that the code is incorrect. It is for illustrative purposes. You did not answer the question.

Comment: Complaints about the question are best written as a comment on the question.  (Click "add comment".)

Comment: @Daniel, have you ever tried laying out long code lines in comments? Comments formatting sucks.

Comment: @pfdevil, if you know that code is incorrect - state it in the question. Otherwise you are asking for lots of "this is undefined behavior` answers.

Comment: He did say "I expected a segmentation fault", which implies he knew the code was incorrect.

Comment: @pfdevil, Usually you illustrate your point with correct code, and not (as you act like) with *deliberately* written wrong code. That's weird.